React 19 "ref as prop" and TypeScript
React 19 introduces a new alternative to the existing forwardRef that is called ref as prop:
https://react.dev/blog/2024/12/05/react-19#ref-as-a-prop
But unfortunately the example provided in the blog post is written in JavaScript, not TypeScript:
function MyInput({ placeholder, ref }) {
  return <input placeholder={placeholder} ref={ref} />
}

//...
<MyInput ref={ref} />

So in TypeScript, what is the correct type the ref prop?

It seems React.RefObject is not correct. I have no error with React.Ref:
import type {Ref} from 'react'

function MyInput({placeholder, ref}: {placeholder?: string; ref?: Ref<HTMLInputElement>}) {
  return <input placeholder={placeholder} ref={ref} />
}

function MyComponent() {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  return <MyInput ref={ref} /> // OK
}

Don't forget mark it as optional (ref?: Ref<...>).

In more complex situations —such as my real case where I used @lexical/react@0.21.0, which appears to not completely compatible with React 19— I wrote the ref like this:
function RichTextEditor({ref}: {ref?: Ref<LexicalEditor>}) {
  // ...
  return (
    // ...
      <EditorRefPlugin
        editorRef={(editorRef) => {
          if (!ref) return
          if (typeof ref === 'function') ref(editorRef)
          else ref.current = editorRef
        }}
      />
    // ...
  )
}


Use React.RefObject:
function MyInput({placeholder, ref}: {
  placeholder: string;
  ref: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
}) {
  return <input placeholder={placeholder} ref={ref} />
}

